# Get type of variable in typescript using compiler api

Tags: typescript

I seem to have trouble getting the type of a variable using the compiler API.
Some context for my sample below.
Since I run everything in memory, I have to create my own compilerhost. This is needed because the typechecker gets created from a 'program' and this expects by default files written to disk.

I try to get the type of "input" and "el". I would expect this to print out "number[]" and "number". This is the same as if I hover over this in VSCode.

However the output that I get is either "{}" or "any".

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong or I have forgotten something, but I don't see what it is.

Best regards,
Ike

```
const code: string = `let input: number[] = [1, 2, 3];
for (let el of input) {
    let x = el * 3;
    if (el > 1) {
        output.push(el);
    }
}`;

const host: ts.CompilerHost = {
  getSourceFile(fileName: string, languageVersion: ts.ScriptTarget, onError?: (message: string) => void): ts.SourceFile {
    console.log("getSourceFile", fileName);
    if (fileName === "test.ts") {
        return ts.createSourceFile(fileName, code, languageVersion);
    }
    if (onError) {
        onError("not found");
    }
    // tsc's declarations don't support strict null checks
    return null as any as ts.SourceFile;
  },
  getDefaultLibFileName: () => "", // "lib.d.ts",
  writeFile: (_fileName, _content) => { },
  getCurrentDirectory: () => ts.sys.getCurrentDirectory(),
  getCanonicalFileName: fileName => ts.sys.useCaseSensitiveFileNames ? fileName : fileName.toLowerCase(),
  getNewLine: () => ts.sys.newLine,
  useCaseSensitiveFileNames: () => ts.sys.useCaseSensitiveFileNames,
  fileExists: (fileName: string) => fileName === "test.ts",
  readFile(fileName: string): string {
    if (fileName === "test.ts") {
      return code;
    }
    return null as any as string;
  },
  resolveModuleNames(_moduleNames: string[], _containingFile: string): ts.ResolvedModule[] {
    throw new Error("unsupported");
  },
  getDirectories(_path: string): string[] {
    throw new Error("unsupported");
  }
};


const program: ts.Program = ts.createProgram(["test.ts"], {allowJs: true}, host);
const checker: ts.TypeChecker = program.getTypeChecker();
const forofke: ts.ForOfStatement = program.getSourceFiles()[0].statements[1];
const stat = forofke.expression;
const type1: ts.Type = checker.getTypeAtLocation(stat);
console.log(checker.typeToString(type1));
const sym: ts.Symbol = checker.getSymbolAtLocation(stat);
const type2: ts.Type = checker.getDeclaredTypeOfSymbol(sym);
console.log(checker.typeToString(type2));
const type3: ts.Type = checker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(sym, stat);
console.log(checker.typeToString(type3));
const type4: ts.Type = checker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(sym, sym.valueDeclaration);
console.log(checker.typeToString(type4));

const stat2 = (<ts.VariableDeclarationList>forofke.initializer).declarations[0].name;
const type12: ts.Type = checker.getTypeAtLocation(stat2);
console.log(checker.typeToString(type12));
const sym2: ts.Symbol = checker.getSymbolAtLocation(stat2);
const type22: ts.Type = checker.getDeclaredTypeOfSymbol(sym2);
console.log(checker.typeToString(type22));
const type32: ts.Type = checker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(sym2, stat2);
console.log(checker.typeToString(type32));
const type42: ts.Type = checker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(sym2, sym2.valueDeclaration);
console.log(checker.typeToString(type42));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compared a 'program' that was loaded from disk against the one in memory from my sample. I noticed that from disk there are 2 sourcefiles in 'program.getSourceFiles()'. The second file is lib.d.ts.

I have changed my sample a little bit and now the output is like I expect it to be.

```
  getSourceFile(fileName: string, languageVersion: ts.ScriptTarget, onError?: (message: string) => void): ts.SourceFile {
    console.log("getSourceFile", fileName);
    if (fileName === "test.ts") {
        return ts.createSourceFile(fileName, code, languageVersion);
    }
    if (fileName === "lib.d.ts") {
        return ts.createSourceFile(fileName, /*READ the file from disk*/, languageVersion);
    }
    if (onError) {
        onError("not found");
    }
    // tsc's declarations don't support strict null checks
    return null as any as ts.SourceFile;
  },
  getDefaultLibFileName: () => "lib.d.ts",
```